# Load images to listbox through dialog.Trouble with binding

Tags: silverlight, image, binding, listbox, load

I should load images to listbox.I have a trouble when I choose images, to listbox added only border without nothing and only one, I have debuged my code and in collection 6 bitmap images, but loaded only 1 border.
1.That is my class Album:

```
  public class Album : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name 
        {
            get { return name; }
            set 
            { 
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }
        private string description;
        public string Description 
        { 
            get
            {
                return description;
            }
            set 
            {
                description = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Description"));
            } 
        }
        private List<BitmapImage> images;
        public List<BitmapImage> Images
        {
            get
            {
                return images;
            }
            set
            {
                images = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Images"));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
        public Album() { }
        public Album(string name, string description, List<BitmapImage> files)
        {
            Name = name;
            Description = description;
            Images = files;
        }
    }
```

2.That my code for child window.When i push button create, I write name, description, and add some photos(please check my method for add is it correct).

```
public partial class DialogCreate : ChildWindow
    {
        private List<BitmapImage> temps = new List<BitmapImage>();
        private string tempName;
        private string tempDescription;
        public List<BitmapImage> Temps 
        {
            get { return temps; }
            set { temps = value; }
        }
        public string TempName
        {
            get { return tempName; }
            set { tempName = value; }
        }
        public string TempDescription
        {
            get { return tempDescription; }
            set { tempDescription = value; }
        }
        private OpenFileDialog addPhoto;
        public DialogCreate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            addPhoto = new OpenFileDialog();
            addPhoto.Multiselect = true;
            addPhoto.Filter = "Image files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        }

        private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tempName = txtGetName.Text;
            tempDescription = txtGetDescription.Text;
            this.DialogResult = true;
        }
        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = false;
        }
        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool result = (bool)addPhoto.ShowDialog();
            if (!result)
                return;
            IEnumerable<FileInfo> file = addPhoto.Files;
            foreach (FileInfo files in file)
            {
                Stream s = files.OpenRead();
                BitmapImage i = new BitmapImage();
                i.SetSource(s);
                temps.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

3.After that I return to:

```
private void CreateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dialogAlbum = new DialogCreate();
    dialogAlbum.Show();
    dialogAlbum.Closed += delegate
    {
        albums.Add(new Album(dialogAlbum.TempName, dialogAlbum.TempDescription, dialogAlbum.Temps));
        AlbumScroll.ItemsSource = albums;
        lsPhoto.ItemsSource = albums;
    };
}
```

4.That my xaml:

```
<ListBox Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" Margin="121,38,171,23" x:Name="lsPhoto" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="144" Width="600">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <Border Width="100" Height="100">
                    <Image x:Name="listPhotos" Source="{Binding}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
                  </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Please help me, what I did wrong?Or give your advertise.

Comment: It looks like for what you are trying to do, you need a scroll viewer of somesort http://deepumi.wordpress.com/2010/04/21/simple-image-scroller-slide-show-using-silverlight-listbox-control/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new class something like this

```
public class ImageInformation:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage ImageInfo { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

I replaced all the places where you use BitmapImage and in mainpage.xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="lsPhoto" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <StackPanel Height="25" Width="25">

                    <Image Height="25" Width="25" Source="{Binding ImageInfo}"></Image>

                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

With these two changes and other impacted changes, my Listbox shows the image that was selected by the user. If you need the solution i tried, send me a mail.